# Is the behavior of XSLT/XQuery regex output implementation-dependent?

Tags: regex, xslt, xpath, xquery

Using the regular expression specifications defined for XPath and XQuery, is it possible for two different implementations of `fn:analyze-string`, given as inputs the same regex and match strings, to return different results and still be considered conforming to the W3C Recommendation? Or should the same inputs always return the same results across different XQuery and XSLT processors?

Specifically, I am asking about the content of `match`, `non-match`, `group`, and `@nr` values, not the base URIs or node identities (which are clearly defined as implementation dependent).

Comment: I have changed the terminology in the title in a way that I believe matches your intent better (see explanations in my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are one or two very minor aspects in which the spec is implementation-dependent:

- The vendor is allowed to decide which version of Unicode to adopt as the baseline. There are some changes between versions of Unicode, for example changes to character categories, that can affect the outcome of expressions like \p{Cn} or \p{IsGreek}, or the question of whether two characters are considered case-variants of each other.
- The rules for captured substrings are not quite precise in edge cases. The spec gives an example: For example given the regular expression (a*)+ and the input string "aaaa", an implementation might legitimately capture either "aaaa" or a zero length string as the content of the captured subgroup.

Beyond that, the results should be the same across processors. But of course, this is one area where processors might decide that 100% conformance is just too hard - for example in Saxon-JS, we decided to do the best we could using the Javascript 6 regex engine, which certainly leaves us short of 100% conformance with the XPath rules.

Answer (score 1):

One must distinguish between three aspects of the terminology that are crucial:

- **Nondeterminism**, which means that the same function/expression may return different results when evaluated several times with the same parameters/context (with the same implementation, in the same query).
- **Implementation-dependent behavior**, which means that implementations may behave differently for a specific feature (but this does not mean that it cannot be deterministic within the same implementation).
- **Implementation-defined behavior**, which is the same as implementation-dependent behavior, except that the implementation must document its behavior precisely so users can rely on it.

My understanding from the XQuery specification, but also from the XML Schema specification which defines the regular expression language, is that two implementations must return the same results to a call to `fn:analyze-string`, considerations on the enclosing element nodes left aside.

The XQuery specification says that the *nondeterminism* of `fn:analyze-string` is only due, as mentioned in the question, to the fact that the node identity may or may not be the same across repeated and identical calls.

The base URI and prefixes are *implementation-dependent*, and my understanding is that it is still implicitly meant that they must be chosen deterministically within a query.

Unless I overlooked something, the XML Schema specification does not seem to give any leeway to implementors on regular expressions. XQuery extends XML Schema regular expressions, but the only *implementation-dependent* feature is the capturing of some groups, which is only relevant for replacements.